# Understanding and using an API

Tags: c#, facebook, azure-cognitive-services

How is an API used? I have been learning and working with c# console application for 3 months now. I have never developed a real software. 
Now I want to get my hands dirty by building a bot on Messenger Platform that will use Microsoft Cognitive services apis.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

So, as I read this, you're asking two questions here:

- How is an API used?
- How is the Microsoft Cognitive services API used?

I can't answer the second one -- I've never used the Microsoft Cognitive services API -- but I can answer the first one.

An API is basically a well-defined set of functions and objects that you can use to do work that you don't want to do yourself (or work you *can't* do yourself).  Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface):

> In general terms, it's a set of clearly defined methods of
>   communication between various software components.

I like to think of it as a set of classes, objects, calls, etc. that do one of two things:

- Prevent me from reinventing the wheel every time I write code, or
- Allow me access to things that I don't normally have an easy way to access.

In the first case, there's a lot of things that you do pretty often.  Working with lists, connecting to databases, and getting data from corporate databases are some examples.  APIs allow you to skip writing your own code for that, instead providing you with the ability to use the API classes and methods to do whatever you want.

Take a simple example.  Let's say you have a list with an unknown number of items.  You could write your own linked list.  Then, the next time you want to write an application and you need to do that again, you could write your own linked list *again*.  But... you don't have to.  The .NET Framework provides a set of classes such as `List<T>` that have everything you want to do on them already there for you.  You can add items, remove them, access them, etc. without ever having to write your own code to do it yourself -- you just call `Add()`, `Remove()` and other methods.  And, since it's all based on an interface (`IList`), all you have to know is the `IList` interface and you can use just about any class that implements it.  The interface becomes the contract by which you can interact with the rest of the class -- it's the definition of what you will play with, and you can rest assured that it won't likely change without some really, *really* good reason.

Another example would be the set of classes you would use to access a SQL Server database -- you don't have to write all the low-level connection code because it's already done for you.  You just use the classes provided, feed them the data you want, and let them do all the heavy lifting.

Those two examples are both a form of API.

(It's worth pointing out here that I never had a formal computer science education, so there might be plenty to nitpick there.  I learned basically on my own with only a few school classes, so this is how I define APIs mentally.)

The second type of API is typified by something like the Google Maps API.  This is something that provides you information you might not otherwise have.  In this case, you don't have access to Google's database and algorithms, nor would you want it -- sure, you can get a list of locations, but do you want to rewrite the algorithms that calculate the best route between two cities?  Instead of making you do that, Google provides a simple, well-documented URL that you can hit.  You call that location, feed it the data you need, and it pops out the results you want to use.

The important thing here is that APIs do three things.  First, they provide a location or class you can use that's well-documented, so that you know what you need in order to use it.  Think of the Google Maps example above -- you can easily find out what the URL is and what data it expects, then you just call the URL with the data and boom, you're done.  Second, they're reusable.  Feed Google Maps (or the .NET Framework's `List<T>` class) the same data twice, and you'll get the same results twice.  Finally, they do something you don't want to do on your own.  I don't want to keep writing a class that manages an array internally and let's me add to it dynamically, so I just use `List<T>` instead.

Really, I've found in my career that programming, in no small part, is an exercise in reuse.  If you're writing the same code multiple times, that code is a good candidate for a function or class.  If I keep writing the same classes that manage a particular type of file (for example, a custom file type that I use in multiple applications), those classes are candidates for a separate library that I can import into other applications.  APIs are examples of reusable code blocks that let you keep from having to do the same thing over, and over, and over again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please how can I use a node.js api in my C# program?

Comment: You're getting into a whole can of worms that can't be answered in a simple way.  I also have little experience with nodejs.  I would suggest starting with nodejs.org or a google search (such as "using nodejs with C#", which I tried).

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample Visual Studio C# solution files from Microsoft, for example here for the Speech API: 
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStartedCSharpDesktop#Step1

the github repo giving an example cognitive vision app for windows desktop is here:
https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-vision-windows
see sample WPF folder.

These should just work as is.

In your console app, in order to use other APIs (a web APIs that is), you need to make a HttpClient that sends a web request to a website, and waits (or listens) for the reply. When the reply comes, you process the reply.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

If you want to experiment with a given webAPI, install Postman on Chrome (google for it), and use this to talk to APIs. Postman can generate code directly in C# when you have your query working correctly (it will also output other languages like Python if you want).